# How do I read the kanji in this ad for mascara?

Tags: kanji, definitions, copywriting

On the train yesterday, I came across this ad, which is just for some mascara or whatever:

[image: mascara ad]

Sorry it's a little blurry. The text is `凛{りん}と際立{きわだ}つ艶ロング`。

I'm just a little unclear on a couple of things.

For the first kanji, `凛{りん}`, my dictionaries say it means "cold", but I can't see how that connects to mascara. Is that the right meaning?

The other question is on the last kanji, `艶`. Is it read `つや` or `えん`? The different readings seem to have different meanings, but they could both apply. `つや` is "gloss, glaze, charm" and other meanings, while `えん` is "charming, fascinating". Which is it?

Comment: I wonder if the dual-meaning is a play on words type of thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I think it's usually written as [`凛{りん}と`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8&stype=0&dtype=3) rather than [`凛{りん}`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%87%9C&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=120634800000&pagenum=1), meaning "dignified".

Secondly I think it's most likely [`艶{つや}`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%84/UTF-8/) as in `つやつや` "glossy/shiny" as I've often seen `つやつやとした` in reference to shiny hair, and `つやロング` gets lots of relevant search results but `えんロング` doesn't seem to.

> 凛{りん}と際{きわ}立{だ}つ艶{つや}ロング
>   "Glossy long (eyelashes) that stand out dignified."

Comment: I swear on all that is good and holy that before when I looked up 凛 I got just "cold", and now after seeing your answer, when I look it up, I'm seeing "cold, frigid, bracing, dignified". I don't know what happened there. Also: it never occured to me to do as you did, which was Google the phrases and see which got more hits and is more likely to be the common reading. I now have a new tool in my study. Nice. So thanks for that, too :)

Comment: @DaveMG No worries :)

Comment: Good explanation of the terms asked for in the question, but the translation at the end is a bit shaky. 艶ロング is a noun referencing the eyelashes in a descriptive way, and 凛と際立つ is modifying that noun, not serving as an imperative. (Also, I believe 艶ロング more normally refers to hair -- note that ロング can be short for ロングヘア, see also 艶髪ロング -- and so I would guess that the point is using a term that would normally reference shiny long hair to describe eyelashes instead, to create some kind of visual impression / comparison. The gloss of long hair is easily imagined and translated to eyelashes.)

Comment: @Hyperworm Thanks for the explanation! I was thinking that might be the case, but I wasn't sure how it could be translated. I think it's because "eyelashes" is implied rather than explicit. For now I've changed it to "Glossy long (eyelashes) that stand out dignified."